# How to sort collection using complex function in Meteor (MongoDB)

Tags: mongodb, sorting, meteor

I have the complex formula `p / a^5` I want to sort a collection with, where `p` and `a` are attributes of the collection `Items`.

Is there any possible way to do it in Meteor (MongoDB)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **[aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/)** for this. You can structure your aggregation pipeline so that it performs the exponential function by using the arithmetic operator **[`$multiply`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/multiply/#exp._S_multiply)**, calling it `n` number of times where `n` is the exponent.

For example, the following aggregation pipeline will add an extra field `r` which is the result of the operation `p / a^5`.

For a start, in mongo shell create some sample documents in the `exponents` collection:

```
for(x=0; x < 10; x++){ db.exponents.insert({p: 5*x, a: x }); }
```

Generate the pipeline:

```
var pipeline = [
    {
        "$match" : {
            "a" : {
                "$gt" : 0
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project" : {
            "p" : 1,
            "a" : 1,
            "r" : {
                "$divide" : [
                    "$p",
                    {
                        "$multiply" : [
                            "$a",
                            "$a",
                            "$a",
                            "$a",
                            "$a"
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$sort" : {
            "r" : 1
        }
    }
];
```

Running the pipeline with the sample documents above :

```
db.exponents.aggregate(pipeline);
```

**Output**:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("561d1ced3d8f561c1548d393"),
            "p" : 45,
            "a" : 9,
            "r" : 0.0007620789513793629
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("561d1ced3d8f561c1548d392"),
            "p" : 40,
            "a" : 8,
            "r" : 0.001220703125
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("561d1ced3d8f561c1548d391"),
            "p" : 35,
            "a" : 7,
            "r" : 0.002082465639316951
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("561d1ced3d8f561c1548d390"),
            "p" : 30,
            "a" : 6,
            "r" : 0.003858024691358025
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("561d1ced3d8f561c1548d38f"),
            "p" : 25,
            "a" : 5,
            "r" : 0.008
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("561d1ced3d8f561c1548d38e"),
            "p" : 20,
            "a" : 4,
            "r" : 0.01953125
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("561d1ced3d8f561c1548d38d"),
            "p" : 15,
            "a" : 3,
            "r" : 0.06172839506172839
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("561d1ced3d8f561c1548d38c"),
            "p" : 10,
            "a" : 2,
            "r" : 0.3125
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("561d1ced3d8f561c1548d38b"),
            "p" : 5,
            "a" : 1,
            "r" : 5
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

You can set up a generic helper function for generating the pipeline code to extract **[`$project`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** operators with the arithmetic operators from the document representation of a power function. As aggregate isn't supported yet in Meteor, use the **[meteorhacks:aggregate](https://atmospherejs.com/meteorhacks/aggregate)** package that adds proper aggregation support for Meteor. This package exposes `.aggregate` method on `Mongo.Collection` instances.

Add to your app with

```
meteor add meteorhacks:aggregate
```

Then simply use `.aggregate()` function together with the generic function to generate the pipeline to use as the `.aggregate()` argument below:

```
function power(exponent) {
    var multiply = [];
    for (var count = 0; count < exponent; count++){
        multiply.push("$a");
    }    
    return [
        { $match: { a: { $gt: 0} } },
        {
            $project: {
                p: 1, a: 1, r : { $divide: [ "$p", { $multiply: multiply } ] } 
            }
        },
        {
            "$sort": { r: 1 }
        }
    ];
}

var pipeline = power(5),
    exponents = new Mongo.Collection('exponents'),
    result = exponents.aggregate(pipeline);
```

Comment: What if the `p` value for each entity increases by 1 each hour?

Comment: Not sure if I got your other question correctly but I think you would get better responses if you open up a new question detailing what you have tried if the value of `p` changes. I guess you would need to run the aggregation based on a counter or setTimeout?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do this. I'd suggest adding another field that stores the value of `p / a^5`. E.g. let's say you called this field `pResult`, then you could just do:

```
collection.find(selector, {sort: {pResult: 1}});
```

Comment: I thought about this approach, but what if `a` changes over time, say, each hour I should update the value of `a`?

Answer (score 0):

You can just `fetch()` the collection, then do the sort using the regular `Array.prototype.sort` or `_.sortBy`. However, this destroys fine-grained reactivity, so if your collection is large or the elements being rendered are complex enough, and the collection changes a lot over time, then you might have performance problems.

```js
Template.whatever.helpers({
    items: function () {
        return _.sortBy(Items.find().fetch(), function (item) {
            return item.p / Math.pow(item.a, 5);
        });
    }
});
```

```html
<template name="whatever">
    {{#each items}}
        <!-- ... -->
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

If you need fine-grained reactivity, you could look at my package [collection-view](https://github.com/cg5-/collection-view/), although I don't consider it production ready.